# Heap Corruption with malloc, struct and char *

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I seem to have a memory corruption in my C program. I used `_ASSERTE( _CrtCheckMemory( ) );` to find the problem statement and it breaks on a line that says `scep_conf->engine_str = NULL;` right before it. So if I understood it correctly, the malloc before that broke something, right?

So this is the part of the code that causes the issue:

```
scep_conf = (SCEP_CONF *) malloc(sizeof(scep_conf));
scep_conf->engine = (struct scep_engine_conf_st *) malloc(sizeof(struct scep_engine_conf_st));
scep_conf->engine_str = NULL;
```

The definitions from the header:

```
typedef struct {
    struct scep_engine_conf_st *engine;
    char *engine_str;
} SCEP_CONF;

struct scep_engine_conf_st{
    char *engine_id;
    char *new_key_location;
    int storelocation; 
    char *dynamic_path;
    char *module_path; 
    int engine_usage;
};

SCEP_CONF *scep_conf;
```

Basically I don't get why it would corrupt my memory here. I am new to C and so there may be something obvious I am not seeing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
scep_conf = (SCEP_CONF *) malloc(sizeof(scep_conf));
```

as it only allocates enough memory for a `SCEP_CONF*`, not a `SCEP_CONF`. it should be:

```
scep_conf = malloc(sizeof(*scep_conf)); /* cast unnecessary. */
```

Worth reading [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)